# Apache KeepAlive in child location not working

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to turn keep-alive connections off for a requests to a child folder in Apache, but when I reload the config I get the following error:

```
KeepAlive not allowed here
```

Here's my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin mark@example.com
  ServerName example.com

  DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite
  DirectoryIndex index.html

  <Location /subfolder>
    KeepAlive Off
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried using `<Directory>` as well, but no go there either.

Any ideas? I'd rather not turn keep-alive off for the whole site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the allowed context in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#keepalive).  `KeepAlive` is ***only*** allowed in the main server block or directly in a `<VirtualHost>` block - not in a `Directory` context (which is what `<Location>` counts as).

Dare I ask why you're trying to turn `KeepAlive` off?  It's a good thing - leave it on if at all possible.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the virtual host context would include everything within that - it seems that's not the case, thanks.

Comment: The binary files in the child directory are always requested by a client who is after that just resource (i.e. there is only ever one request per client, they are not web pages or web page assets). Combined with this, the files get requested by a large number of clients per day, so I'd rather not leave connections open beyond the lifecycle of each request - there's no need, no further requests will be made by the client in the near future.

Comment: If connections are the concern, just set a reasonably low `KeepAliveTimeout` - 5 seconds or so should be fine.